# Putting a SIM to another phone and placing it back again. Any side-effects?

Tags: samsung, hardware, huawei, sim-card

If I have a phone `A` that I use and I get a new phone `B` and I take out the SIM card from `A` and insert it in `B` and try it out.
When I put back the SIM to `A` will it be exactly as was before, or could this have any sort of side-effects to `A`? Can `B` which is a brand new phone e.g. write something to the SIM that can create issues to `A` (at least not be in the exact state it was before the test)?

Comment: When re-inserting the sim card to A your MNO may push you again the the APN settings for internet, SMS and MMS. Unless you have modified them there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Robert: I dont know what `your MNO may push you again the the APN settings for internet, SMS and MMS.` means. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: See you cellular settings in Android. Yu will find an APN configuration. usually as a user you don't have to modify it, it you could and you you place the SIM again in the phone your MNO could overwrite your changes. Just search for APN and Android and you will get an explanation.

Comment: @Robert: I will search that. When you say `Unless you have modified them there shouldn't be a problem.` what is an example of a problem?

Comment: Well it's a configuration that decides how Internet, MMS and so on works. Sk what problem can you get? Yes something doesn't work but as you doesn't seem to know what an APN setting is you can't get problems as you can't have modified something, otherwise you would have known about APN settings.